# Why the ID value is not auto-generated with IDENTITY in the Oracle database?

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, maven

Oracle database is used in the SpringBoot project of a company I work for. There is no problem while the project is running, but when the `save()` command runs, it gives an error because it cannot generate an `ID` value with the `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` annotation.

We are developing the project in Intellij IDEA application, I use Oracle database and I get the project codes from BitBucket site.

The problem is that although everything is the same, i.e. Java, Maven, SpringBoot, Hibernate, OJDBC and codes, why my computer has this problem while my other friends do not have this problem.

Spring version: 2.4.1

Java Version: jdk1.8.0_202

Maven Version: apache-maven-3.6.3

Oracle Version: 12c

Hibernate version:

[image]

OJDBC version: OJDBC8

These versions are the same as those of my colleagues, there are no differences, but on my computer the `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` annotation for the Oracle database does not work.

But instead of

`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`

`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ODF_SMS_NTF_SEQ")`

When I wrote

`@SequenceGenerator(name = "ODF_SMS_NTF_SEQ", sequenceName = "ODF_SMS_NTF_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)`

it worked but in my teammates' projects

`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`

works.

There is no problem with project or database authorizations because `SEQUENCE` works and `IDENTITY` does not work

Hibernate:

```
insert into odf_sms_ntf (sms_ntf_id, cdate, cuser, bsn_inter_spec_id, cust_id, data_tp_id, dealers_code, edate, is_verified, ref_code, row_id, sdate, sms_val, tel_num, try_count, user_id) values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Error message:

```
2023-11-17 03:16:51.889  WARN IN0001026270162 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper             : SQL Error: 17068, SQLState: 99999
2023-11-17 03:16:51.889 ERROR IN0001026270162 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper             : Çağrıda geçersiz bağımsız değişkenler var
2023-11-17 03:16:51.891 ERROR IN0001026270162 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.AssertionFailure                     : HHH000099: an assertion failure occurred (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in etiya.commerce.backend.odf.common.entity.security.OdfSmsNtfEntity entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
2023-11-17 03:16:51.904  INFO IN0001026270162 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] e.c.b.c.w.DceProfiler                    : execution-time-error: 26099 ms -`http://localhost:8080/odf/security/verification/sendSms` - etiya.commerce.backend.odf.controller.rest.security.OdfSecurityVerificationController.sendSms
2023-11-17 03:16:51.905 ERROR IN0001026270162 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] .c.b.o.c.w.OdfCustomRestExceptionHandler : error id : 1700209011905 - url: `http://localhost:8080/odf/security/verification/sendSms`
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in etiya.commerce.backend.odf.common.entity.security.OdfSmsNtfEntity entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkId(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getValues(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:232)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1362)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1349)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.beforeQuery(NativeQueryImpl.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1591)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1641)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:1
```

Although my project and the necessary files such as Java, Maven, Ojdbc are the same with my other teammates, the `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` annotation can generate an `id` value on the computer of my other teammates, but why it cannot generate an `id` value with `IDENTITY` in my project.
I am investigating what is the cause of this.

Comment: It would be very helpful to see your full pom file... https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot/#support Spring Boot version is long out of updates ... also Maven version (https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) and your JDK 8 version also ...

Answer (score 0):

The setting `GenerationType.IDENTITY` means that the database would increment the value of the `id`. It works with other databases like MySQL, but it never works with Oracle database. You should use a sequence to increment the `id` or use a trigger.

However if you have Oracle 12c or higher then you can create a table manually without DDL auto-generation.

For example:

This is a table with auto-generated primary key:

```sql
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (
  ID NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY
);
```

Also make sure you set `Oracle12cDialect` property value to your Hibernate configuration.